# using schedule python library to set a Timer

Tags: python, timer, schedule

Dears
Excuse me if you find that my question is stupid.
I need your help to figure out a way to use the [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python library to make a led ON forexample for 2 minutes an OFF for example for 100 minutes all days (all the time). PS : without using sleep method.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the post to make my need more clear

Comment: Maybe take a look here https://github.com/DigonIO/scheduler.
The python scheduler library is an alternative to the schedule library with support for asyncio and timezones. Disclosure: I am one of the authors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer to your question is pretty much in the documentation you posted. You could try something like this:

```
import schedule
import time

def job_on():
    print("Turn LED on here")

def job_off():
    print("Turn LED off here")

schedule.every().hour.at(":58").do(job_on)
schedule.every().hour.at(":00").do(job_off)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I actually need, in fact I do not have a fixed time at which the led should be ON or OFF. My inputs are only ON duration and OFF duration.

Comment: Try something like this:
`schedule.every(100).minutes.do(job_on); time.sleep(60); schedule.every(100).minutes.do(job_off)`. Should keep the light on for a minute every 100 minutes.